# trouble coding a block of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I just wanted to ask a question about a hmk assignment concerning the for loop. Basically we have to use 'for' to make a block of numbers look like this:

```
01234501  
12345012  
23450123  
34501234  
45012345  
50123450  
01234501  
12345012
```

This is my code so far:

```
for x in range (-1,7):
    for y in range (8):
        x=x+1
        if x<=5:
            print(x,end="")
        else:
            print(abs(x-6),end="")
    print()
```

which gives me:

```
01234501
12345012
23450123
34501234
45012345
50123456
01234567
12345678
```

I'd be very grateful for any pointers! Thanks!

Comment: what exactly u want?

Comment: If I could get any pointers to what I should be doing/getting wrong with the code it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Try using **modulo** `%` instead of your if-statement. `print(x%6, end="")`

Comment: @PaulRooney I'm sorry that I can't really be more specific, I'm just working off of the powerpoint that the professor put up and all it says is that we should "print the numbers below" if that clarifies anything.

Comment: Good catch @Jonas

Comment: @Jonas, thanks so much! You're a real lifesaver :D

Answer (score 2):

You need modulo operator `%`:

```
for x in range (-1,7):
    for y in range (8):
        x += 1
        print(x % 6, end='')
    print()
```

Comment: @PaulRooney Try it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this is what you want,

```
for x in range (8):
    for y in range (8):
        print(x%6,end="")
        x += 1
    print()
```